# Need help whit 960 Grid System

Tags: html, css, grid

I have a problem with 960 Grid System.

My english is not so good so I'll show you a picture what I mean:

https://picr.ws/images/0651e9daf54838f294450fae875b25e5.png

I want to push the bottom `grid_4` to the top `grid_4`, instead of it staying under the `grid_8`. Here is my code:

```css
.container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.container .title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

.container .content {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>960 Grid System</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/960gs/0/960.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <main class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_4">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="title">grid_4</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_8">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="title">grid_8</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="grid_4">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="title">grid_4</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put both the left grids into one grid_4.

```css
.container {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.container .title {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.container .content {
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.grid_4, .grid_8 {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>960 Grid System</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/960gs/0/960.css">
  </head>
<body>

<main class="container_12">
  <div class="grid_4">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Title in container 1</div>
      <div class="content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Title in container 2</div>
      <div class="content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_8">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">grid_8</div>
      <div class="content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

I've put in extra background color to better show, how it works.